# Why doesn't tracepoint trace calls to methods like `String#size`?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to track all method calls made in the program using `Tracepoint`. `Tracepoint` doesn't track calls to certain classes. For example:

```
class A; def call_to_method_a; puts 'test3' end; end

TracePoint.trace(:call, :c_call) do |tp|
    p [tp.lineno, tp.defined_class, tp.method_id, tp.event]
end

'test2'.size
# No Tracepoint output

A.new.call_to_method_a
# [26, A, :call_to_method_a, :call]
```

`Tracepoint` records the call for line `A.new.call_to_method_a`, but I'd expect it to also track calls to `String#size'. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It is because those methods are defined in C, not in Ruby. `:call` only traces Ruby-defined method calls. To trace C-defined methods, you need to use `:c_call`.

Comment: Good call, I forgot to add `:c_call` as an argument. I changed the example a bit to add c_call, but calling 'test2'.size still doesn't show a call by Tracepoint. Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to look at the generated code. It could very well be that because both the contents of the string and the target of the method call are known at compile time (and `String#size` has no side-effects), the compiler optimizes away the call entirely. It is, after all, dead code, and has no effect. You didn't specify which implementation you are using, but I know that at least JRuby does perform dead code elimination.